# What security risks are associated with using a unofficial .vmdk?

Tags: virtualization, windows-10

I'm in the process of installing macOS Sierra on a virtual machine (VirtualBox) using a [virtual machine hard disk file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1TeIMG33wLPa3lnTnF1ZVFMWVE) retrieved from [this site](https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-sierra-virtualbox-windows/). What are the security risks I'm running by using this "random" `.vmdk` to create a virtual machine on my pc (Windows 10)?

Comment: @Limit I think it is sufficiently different. OP asks about using untrusted VM images. The other question focuses on the limits of VM isolation.

Comment: @Jedi I was thinking in terms of the impact on the host machine.

Comment: The question could also be interpreted as asking what it means to the security of the data processed inside the VM. Because of the many ways to interpret the question it could reasonably be closed as too broad or unclear what you are asking.